# How do I calculate the height of a circle with a offset on the x axis

Tags: math

Given the image:
[image: Circle height illustration]

"Distance Y" is equal to 2x radius of the circle, but if I have a "Distance X" offset then how do I calculate "Distance Y"? I will always know the "Distance X" offset and the radius of the circle, is that enough information to calculate "Distance Y" and how do I do it?

Thank you
Søren

Comment: There doesn't appear to be a computer involved here; you should ask this on [math.se]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just Pythagoras:

```
Y = 2 * sqrt(R^2 - X^2)
```

Draw a triangle connecting the centre of the circle, one end of "distance Y" and the centre of "distance Y" and it should be obvious.

Comment: I was just about to say the same thing - this is correct

Comment: I drew the piccie but haven't yet figured out the sums. You know distance from centre to the dissecting line ant radius. But, how do you know angle of hypoteneuse to Y at dissecting line? (think  that's what I mean!)

Comment: @wmorrison365: you don't need to know any of the angles, it's just Pythagoras. The hypotenuse is R, the longer side is X, so you just need to find the shorter side, which is also equal to Y / 2.

Comment: Oh yes, ha it is easy to see when I draw it, but I probably never would have come up with the solution. Thank you